# Dynamic RMM Configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-area

I'm trying to configure dynamic from and reply Sender Profiles using AMPscript. The overview in the Support Portal leaves something to be desired:

[**Create a Dynamic RMM Configuration**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/reply_mail_management/create_a_dynamic_rmm_configuration/)

I have two Data Extensions -

1. CustomerContact (my main customer list - includes RepID field)
2. SendasSalesRep (my Sales Rep table - SalesName, SalesFromeMail, SalesReplyeMail, RepID)

I have four Content Areas -

1. %%=Lookup("SendasSalesRep","SalesReplyeMail","RepID",RepID)=%%
2. %%=Lookup("SendasSalesRep","SalesName","RepID",RepID)=%%
3. %%=Lookup("SendasSalesRep","SalesFromeMail","RepID",RepID)=%%
4. %%=Lookup("SendasSalesRep","SalesName","RepID",RepID)=%%

Here are the iterations of AMPscript I have tried.  All have failed.

1st Try:  Will not save to Sender Profile - Throws this error:

> (A problem occurred updating your sender profile. Please contact Customer Service for additional information. Name: Neutron Industries - Send as Rep External Key: 82 Invalid Sender Profile state.    ClientID: 7296105   SenderProfileID: e5939ac4-fed1-e611-b70d-1402ec67bf94   Sender Profile Name: Neutron Industries - Send as Rep   CustomerKey: 82The FromName AMPScript contains the following errorsInvalid Function Call - "ContentArea("SendasSalesRepSendNameDynamic")"The FromEmail AMPScript contains the following errorsInvalid Function Call - "ContentArea("SendasSalesRepSendAddressDynamic")"The FromEmail AMPScript contains the following errorsInvalid Function Call - "ContentArea("SendasSalesRepReplyAddressDynamic")"The FromName AMPScript contains the following errorsInvalid Function Call - "ContentArea("SendasSalesRepReplyNameDynamic")"

- From Name: `%%=ContentArea("SendasSalesRepSendNameDynamic")=%%`
- From eMail: `%%=ContentArea("SendasSalesRepSendAddressDynamic")=%%`
- Reply Name: `%%=ContentArea("SendasSalesRepReplyNameDynamic")=%%`
- Reply eMail: `%%=ContentArea("SendasSalesRepReplyAddressDynamic")=%%`

2nd Try: Saves without error - Gets canceled after send

- From Name: `%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\SendasSalesRepSendNameDynamic")=%%`
- From eMail: `%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\SendasSalesRepSendAddressDynamic")=%%`
- Reply Name: `%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\SendasSalesRepReplyNameDynamic")=%%`
- Reply eMail: `%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\SendasSalesRepReplyAddressDynamic")=%%`

3rd Try: Saves without error - Gets canceled after send

- From Name:`%%=ContentArea("1138")=%%`
- From eMail: `%%=ContentArea("1137")=%%`
- Reply Name: `%%=ContentArea("1136")=%%`
- Reply eMail: `%%=ContentArea("1135")=%%`

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: You should add any error messages you encounter verbatim.

Comment: I believe there is a Business Rule that Support needs to turn on as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest starting with adding the AMPScript for all four content areas to the body of your email to ensure they function properly.

Your #2 and #3 examples should work, but without knowing what's in your content areas, we don't have much to go on.

**Update**

I'm not a big fan of utilizing raw personalization strings.  It's much better to code it defensively, assuming that either `RepID` won't exist in the sending audience or won't be found by the lookup.  Here's an example for the reply email:

```
%%[

var @RepID, @sendName
set @RepID = AttributeValue("RepID")
set @sendName = Lookup("SendasSalesRep","SalesReplyeMail","RepID", @RepId)

if not empty(@sendName) then
  output(concat(@sendName))
else
  output(concat("Your Friend"))
endif

]%%
```

You can put this in a Content Area and reference in the RMM config, or you can paste it directly in the RMM field.